# Subscript out of bounds-R error

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I am using createFolds function in R to create folds which is returning successful result. But when I am using loop to perform some calculation on each fold I am getting below error. 
Code is:

```
set.seed(1000)
k <- 10
folds <- createFolds(train_data,k=k,list = TRUE, returnTrain = FALSE)
str(folds)
```

This is giving output as:

```
List of 10
 $ Fold01: int [1:18687] 1 8 10 21 22 25 26 29 34 35 ...
 $ Fold02: int [1:18685] 5 11 14 32 40 46 50 52 56 58 ...
 $ Fold03: int [1:18685] 16 20 39 47 49 77 78 83 84 86 ...
 $ Fold04: int [1:18685] 3 15 30 38 41 44 51 53 54 55 ...
 $ Fold05: int [1:18685] 7 9 17 18 23 37 42 67 75 79 ...
 $ Fold06: int [1:18686] 6 31 36 48 72 74 90 113 114 121 ...
 $ Fold07: int [1:18686] 2 33 59 61 100 103 109 123 137 161 ...
 $ Fold08: int [1:18685] 24 64 68 87 88 101 110 130 141 152 ...
 $ Fold09: int [1:18684] 4 27 28 66 70 85 97 105 112 148 ...
 $ Fold10: int [1:18684] 12 13 19 43 65 91 94 108 134 138 ...
```

However below code is giving me error

```
for( i in 1:k ){
  testData <- train_data[folds[[i]], ]
  trainData <- train_data[(-folds[[i]]), ]
}
```

Error is:

```
> for( i in 1:k ){
+   testData <- train_data[folds[[i]], ]
+   trainData <- train_data[(-folds[[i]]), ]
+ }
Error in train_data[folds[[i]], ] : subscript out of bounds
```

I tried with different seed values but I am getting same error.
Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding,  your problem is arising because you are using the whole dataframe `train_data` to create folds.  K-folds can be generated for samples, ie,  rows of the dataset.

For instance:

```
data(spam) # from package kernlab
dim(spam) #has 4601 rows/samples
folds <- createFolds(y=spam$type, k=10, list=T, returnTrain = T) 
# Here, only one column , spam$type, is used 
# and indeed
max(unlist(folds)) #4601
#and these can be used as row indices
head( spam[folds[[4]], ] )
```

Using the whole dataframe is very similar to using a matrix. Such a matrix will first be converted to a vector. Thus a 5x10 matrix will actually be converted to 50 element vector and the values in folds will be corresponding to the indices of this vector. If you try to then use these values as row indices for your dataframe, they will overshoot

```
r <- 8
c <- 10
m0 <- matrix(rnorm(r*c), r, c)
features<-apply(m0, c(1,2), function(x) sample(c(0,1),1))
features
folds<-createFolds(features,4)    
folds
max(unlist(folds)) 

m0[folds[[2]],] # Error in m0[folds[[2]], ] : subscript out of bounds
```